# How do I get the single turnstile symbol?

Tags: symbols, logic

I am trying to replicate a logic symbol that looks like `\models` but has only one horizontal line, and represents a logical deduction. It looks roughly like `|-`.

I have tried Detexify, but it does not seem to recognize the symbol even though it is very simple to draw (and therefore it is unlikely I drew it poorly).

While I could look through the entire list, that seems less practical than asking if anyone is already familiar with it.

Comment: What about `\vdash`?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_%28symbol%29): "In TeX, the turnstile symbol ⊢ is obtained from the command `\vdash`". Of course you could use `\let\yields\vdash` to have a macro that reads more naturally when you look at the TeX source

Comment: vdash was what I was looking for!

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/turnstile is another more powerful option.

Comment: @merlin2011 I only just joined this stack exchange, but I think you should look up the answer to something like that before asking here.  It is more practical for *you* to ask here, but that doesn't make it more practical for everybody else.  You should download "The not so short introduction to latex" (it's on the web as lshort.pdf) or get Kopka and Daly's  Guide to Latex.

Comment: @DeliaRuby, With this question in place, people can now google for "single turnstyle latex" and be immediately brought to an answer. That's the contribution of questions like this one.

Comment: @DeliaRuby, Thank you for the references, also.

Comment: Those who spell it correctly will never find your question; had you spelt it correctly, you would have found the answer. At least, had you searched, you would have found the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your needs are relatively simple, you may want to use `\vdash`. If you are typesetting logic for anything beyond the most elementary level, the standard commands are unlikely to meet your needs. In that case, the `turnstile` package is the answer. This is true both if you need more complex symbols (e.g. triple lines or combinations of single/double/triple) or if you need a turnstile of any kind with subscripts or superscripts, as is usually the case.

## Unicode

A couple of symbols that look like the output caused by the above command:

Assertion: ⊦
Unicode hexadecimal: 0x22a6
In block: Mathematical Operators

Right tack: ⊢
Unicode hexadecimal: 0x22a2
In block: Mathematical Operators

(found with http://shapecatcher.com/)

Comment: Is there a way to enter Unicode for LateX?

Comment: @merlin2011 With the [`newunicodechar` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar) you can do `\newu­ni­codechar{⊢}{\vdash}`.

Comment: To confused Googlers: **I simply needed `\vdash`.**

Comment: @cfr I never intended this answer to be definitive but no one else contributed. Thanks for doing the job.

Comment: I understand and I'm glad you don't mind. I would have added another answer but that isn't possible, so it seemed to me best to make sure the information was included in the existing answer. People say `\vdash` which is fine for really introductory logic, but doesn't work well for anything more advanced. `\vdash` often looks better when it is sufficient, though, and it is easier to use.

Comment: "If you are typesetting logic for anything beyond the most elementary level, the standard commands are unlikely to meet your needs." - This is not true. `\vdash` will perfectly suffice for many advanced applications in logic. No need for the "turnstile" package.